# ADB dump view hierarchy different from UiAutomator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to get an element in a 3rd party android app using its resourceId. When I use the command `adb shell uiautomator dump`, the XML view hierarchy shows the element that I'm looking for. However, when I try to get the element using UiAutomator in Android Studio while running a UITest using 
`device.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(myResourceID))`, there is no such element.

Is there anything that would cause such behavior? I'm very new to Android, so please let me know if I need to include any more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem cannot be extracted from the information you posted. There might be a difference between the dumps.

However, [culebra.dtmilano.com](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) may be of help in your case as you can select Views directly on the tree, as shown here (hovering over Settings)

[image]

and the corresponding Java (in this case) or Python, Kotlin, etc. code is generated assuring the selector for the View is correct

```
@Test
public void culebraGeneratedTest() throws Exception {
    mDevice.findObject(By.desc("Settings").clazz("android.widget.TextView").text("Settings").pkg("com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher")).clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
}
```